# Can I make a roaming profile on a network as a local computer admin?

Tags: networking, roaming-profiles

I am currently in a position where I have an account on a Windows network. I was trying to make another account like this, which currently has local administrative privileges. I was trying to make a roaming account by going to My Computer > Properties > Advanced > User Profiles > and changing it from Local to Roaming, but it won't let me.

My account is currently set on Local for that one computer, but I still have access to it all over the network, only the desktop doesn't change on each computer if I change it on one.

Basically, I'm trying to make a roaming profile that I am able to access on any computer connected to the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a roaming profile, you must edit your account's properties (read: get a network admin to do it) and set the "User profile" path to a network location; for example, `\\thatserver\profiles\ekaj`. The location must be a share or directory owned by your account.

Note that roaming profiles often cause more problems than they solve. For example, the profile is *copied* to the local machine on logon and copied back on logoff; this takes some time. If you log into two computers at once, you will *still* have independent desktops, and they will get merged only when you log out of both. (That is, if you're lucky. It's more likely that older changes will just get overwritten.)